# Citrix : What is the difference between outputmodes

Tags: remote-access, citrix, xenapp, citrix-access-gateway

In Citrix there are four available outputModes:

- OutputModeNormal
- OutputModeWindowless
- OutputModeRenderless
- OutputModeNonHeadless

When using Simulation API I don't see any difference between OutputModeNormal and OutputModeWindowless.

From [documentation](https://www.citrix.com/static/cdn/archivedsdks/icaobjectsdk/ICA_Client_Object_Guide_v10x.pdf), I would expect OutputModeWindowless to show no window on client side, but I get the window whatever I do.

Is this expected, and if yes, what is the real difference ?

I've searched a lot without any success:

- https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/278410-outputmode-windowsless-and-renderless-help-on/

Comment: From the Manual(https://www.citrix.com/static/cdn/archivedsdks/simulsdk/9.x/sim_api_specification_programmers_guide.pdf): Usage Guidelines: OutputMode must be defined only at load-time; that is, before a connection is
launched.

Comment: Hello, thanks but that is what I am doing. Regards