# In LoadRunner what's the difference between ctrx_set_window_ex and ctrx_sync_on_window

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, citrix, microfocus

I am working on a performance test of Citrix application using Load Runner and Citrix Protocol.

I need to wait for a window to appear, and reading the documentation I see I can use one of those:

- [ctrx_sync_on_window](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.53/help/function_reference/Content/citrix_ica/lrFuncRef_ctrx_sync_on_window.htm) : Waits until a window is created or becomes active.
- [ctrx_set_window_ex](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.53/help/function_reference/Content/citrix_ica/lrFuncRef_ctrx_set_window_ex.htm) : Waits a specified time for a window to appear in the Citrix client

But reading their documentation, I don't clearly understand the difference except for the time factor and which one I should use.

I tried each of them, and they are working for me, but I don't know which one is the best.

First Option:

```
ctrx_sync_on_window("Notepad", ACTIVE, 0, 0, 801, 601, "snapshotXX", CTRX_LAST);
```

Second Option:

```
// Wait 5 seconds for Notepad popup to appear
ctrx_win_exist("Notepad",5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctrx_win_exist` is mostly used, when there is a time frame needed until a windows appears/becomes active;
`ctrx_sync_on_window` is part of the synchronization options, such as bitmap sync. It will make sure the windows is located on a specified position.

Usually it depends on the script which one is better to be used

Comment: thanks for your help. Do you by any chance know the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452576/citrix-what-is-the-difference-between-outputmodes ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about Citrix :). I work in the LoadRunner group.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought that as your were answering question on Citrix protocol of Load Runner, you would know the answer to this question.